# Defining function in header file - get different result

Tags: c++, function

I run into a problem which I cant understand. That piece of code I have in main.cpp:

```
void bisection(double a, double b, std::vector<double>& vctr, const double eps)
{
    double x0 = 0.0;

    while( abs(a - b) > eps)
    {
        x0 = (a + b)/2.0; // middle value
        double tmp = poly(x0); // to calculate this value only one time
        double tmpA = poly(a);
        double tmpB = poly(b);

        if( tmp == 0)
            break;

        else if( tmpA * tmp  < 0.0)
            b = x0;

        else if( tmpB * tmp < 0.0)
            a = x0;

        if(tmpB*tmp > 0 && tmpA*tmp >0)
            return;
    }

    vctr.push_back(x0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double a = -12.0, b= 20;
    vector<double> vctr;

    while(a <= b)
    {
        bisection(a, a+0.1, vctr);
        a += 0.1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<vctr.size(); i++)
        cout << vctr[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case everything works. But if define function bisection in header file alg.h or decleare it them and define in alg.cpp it gives me vector of size 321 ((20 + 12)/0.1 + 1 ) filled with zeros. I have completely no idea why. Any help?

Comment: The `bisection` you show has 4 arguments but the one you are calling has 3 - why?

Comment: this code has some bugs and errors. The one mentioned by @Frank wont even let it compile. Another one is `for(int i=0; i<vctr.size(); i++) cout << vctr[0] << endl;` you print the first element many times. Is this how you know it is filled with zeros?

Comment: please post the real code

Comment: If you define `bisection` in _alg.cpp_, you need to recompile it everytime you make a change. Judging by the mistake by Frank your code seems to be linked with an old version of `bisection` which has 3 formal parameters.

Comment: When you place code in a header file, every source file that includes the header file will receive a *copy* of the function.  Linker's don't like this.  Look up "One Definition Rule".  Are you trying to *inline* the function?

Comment: The bisection has 3 arguments because in alg.h i have a declaration of this function with default argument.

I print vctr[0] only for see what was pushed. There should be 2 values (2 zeros of the polynomial). In the other case, is to write vctr.size()

I am using Qt, so maybe that's the problem with linker or compiler. I will try make a new project and write my own makefile.